# Clojure for return result in list?

Tags: list, for-loop, vector, clojure

this code:

```
(vector (first x)
        (for [i (range (dec (count x)))] (+ (nth x i) (nth x (inc i)))) 
        (last x)
)
```

will return [1 (2) 1] for x=[1 1]. How I can make [1 2 1] instead [1 (2) 1] in best practice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simpler way to do what you want:

```
(concat [(first x)] (map + x (rest x)) [(last x)])
```

or if it must be a vector:

```
(into [(first x)] (conj (mapv + x (rest x)) (last x)))
```

Comment: Beautiful better than truth

Answer (score -1):

As a convenient shorthand equivalent to Diego's answer, I would usually use a syntax-quoted expression here:

```
`[~(first x) 
  ~@(map + x (rest x)) 
  ~(last x)]
```

Comment: Syntax-quote is a needless complication that only confuses the situation.

Answer (score -2):

An even more bulletproof solution is:

```
(flatten [ (first x) 
           (map + x (rest x)) 
           (last x) ] )
```

Comment: No. This won't work if the elements of xs are compound things like lists. It's fine for numbers, as here, but there's no particular need for `flatten` and it's a bad habit to get into.

Comment: I must disagree.  `flatten` is the simplest and most reliable way to solve the problem as stated. Premature conjecture about other problems is counterproductive, introduces more complexity, increases the chance of errors, and makes solutions harder to understand.